# How to obtain template hints in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, template-hints

I want to ask that how to turn on template hints and template hint links in admin panel?

Comment: which version in magento1 or magento2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by changing the database directly. If you have something like phpMyAdmin that is a good way to gain access. Enter this SQL.

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

When you are done with path hints just delete the matching record from `core_config_data` Or update the `value` field to `0` instead of deleting the whole record, it will probably be the last one since you've just added it.

Comment: I built a module for enabling hints on admin, hope this can help others  https://github.com/ledian-hymetllari/adminhints

Comment: Don't edit the database. Just use xml: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/349937/46397

Answer (score 4):

If it's for `magento1.x` then go to

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml`

First take backup of this file and change below code

```
<template_hints translate="label">
    <label>Template Path Hints</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default> <!--change this value to 1-->
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</template_hints>
```

And change setting from System->Configuartion->Developer and set template path hint `on`  change this on default level otherwise you cannot see hint on

> Revert this file when you done

Answer (score 3):

If you are a magento developer Modify

**app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php as below:**

```
public function fetchView($fileName)
{
    .......
    .......
    //Commented to show the hints everywhere
    //Line #221
    //if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) { 
        ......
        ......
        if (self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks) { //Comment if you want to see the block hints
        ........
        ........
        } //Comment if you want to see the block hints
    //}
    .......
    .......
    //Line #251
    //if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) {
    .......
    //}
}
```

**DON'T FORGET TO REVERT THIS ONCE YOU ARE DONE**

Comment: You should never edit the core files, even if you are a developer.!

Comment: Normally I agree, but as long as it doesn't end up in version control, everything is fine :-)

Comment: @Manashvibirla That's true if it is something required for a longterm run. In this case, this is just to view a file path and I don't see any mistake if the changes can be reverted in the local environment itself.

Answer (score 2):

If it is Magento 2

```
Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes
```

Comment: The solution for Magento 1 enables the path hints for frontend, not admin panel. There is no configuration in magento 1 to enable path hints for admin

Comment: Yes, i modified my answer.

Comment: I have done this but not able to see template hints I am using 2.1.7 is there anything to append to url

Answer (score 1):

You can enable template hints for frontend and backend using extension "Easy Template Path Hints". It is beneficial in many ways as it provides hints of both admin and frontend. You can access hints by altering URL with certain keyword postfix after URL. There is no need to enable Magento default template hint.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.htmlts.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable template path hints in magento-1.9 version. You have two methods.

1. First method:

```
System > Configuration > Current configuration scope (at top left) > change to main website > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes
```

2. Second method:

You can enable template hints for frontend and backend using extension "Easy Template Path Hints".https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

Comment: You must not have read the question. Your solution is for frontend hints and the question is about adminhtml.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 go to `core_config_data` table, look for path `dev/debug/template_hints_admin` and set its value to `1`.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '1' WHERE `path` = 'dev/debug/template_hints_admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which you can enable/disable magento admin pages template hints.

One through FTP & other through Database.

FTP : Edit the app/etc/config.xml

```
<config>

    ...

    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>

</config>
```

DATABASE: Insert these 2 rows into database.

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),
('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

[Here](http://nikinpages.com/enable-magento-admin-pages-template-path-hints/) you have additional details about disabling or restoring the changes back.

Answer (score 0):

open /app/etc/local.xml and add the follow code

```
<config>

    ...

    <websites>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </websites>
</config>
```

or you can do with database tables as follows

> INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
>          VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers about temporarilym modifying the database are just the wrong thing to do.

I have always done this.

Locate this file:

```
/app/etc/local.xml
```

And add this to it:

```
<config>

    ...

    <websites>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </websites>
</config>
```

I went one further than this and created an extension:

Start with the module xml file `app/etc/modules/HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And then do this in the config file `app/code/community/HenryHayes/AdminTemplateHints/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints>
    </modules>
    <websites>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </websites>
</config>
```

To switch it off set active to false in `app/etc/modules/HenryHayes_AdminTemplateHints.xml`:

```
<active>false</active>
```