# Downloadable Information is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, ce-1.9.1.1

I tried to create downloadable product following the [documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-downloadable.html) I failed in step 3.

My tab with "Downloadable Information" is empty:

[image]

I spend a few hours trying to debug this. There is no error in JS console or magento log. I also disabled modules. Cleared cache of course.

`Mage_Downloadable_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable::__construct()` is called but `_toHtml()` is not (as far as I can tell). I read though related classes, templates and layouts but I could not figure out from where it should be called or what the problem is.

I am totally lost. Any advice where to dig deeper?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable display errors in index.php:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

or add this

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Check again if will display any php error. 
Enable template hints for admin to see which template is showing there . 
If there is any custom module , disable / debug.

Comment: I did not get any errors and template hints do not show up in admin. [Tried every trick in the book](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138613/how-to-obtain-template-hints-in-admin-panel/138619).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by enabling a disabled module.

`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output -> Mage_Downloadable -> Enable`

Then click on Save Config and it might work.